# Composer install package in other directory

Tags: composer-php

I have the following composer.json:

```
    {
    "name": "fuel/fuel",
    "type": "metapackage",
    "description": "The FuelPHP framework",
    "keywords": ["framework"],
    "homepage": "http://fuelphp.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "FuelPHP Development Team",
            "email": "team@fuelphp.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "monolog/monolog": "1.5.*",
        "fuelphp/upload": "2.0.1",
        "twig/twig": "1.15.1",
        "vesselinv/fuel-sprockets": "1.0.x-dev"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "vendor"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php oil r install"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

My problem is, that composer automatically installs the sprockets packages to /fuel/packages/sprockets, but I have change the framework structure a little bit, so that my "package" dir is under /packages/. How can I change this composer behavior?

I need it only for "vesselinv/fuel-sprockets"!

Comment: "fuel/fuel" certainly isn't your own package name, but that of the framework you are using. You should change it to avoid confusion. Additionally, the description and most importantly the license should be also changed, otherwise you are licensing your work under the MIT license.

Comment: Thank you for that info, but since it is basically only an experiment with that new library, the code will not be sold/published/whatever. I am just tring to find out, how to get it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `vendor-dir` under `config` to `packages`

[Doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#config):

> **vendor-dir**: Defaults to vendor. You can install dependencies into a different directory if you want to.

See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27735674/2486953